# Navbar hover drop down padding

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down nav menu that shows up when you hover over a specific nav item. Everything works correctly except for the "videos" drop down. The hover color change doesn't extend fully to the right. This is obviously because of the padding that is set. The problem is that I don't know how to fix this without messing with the "photography" item. I feel like an idiot, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this to work.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5QNq/)

**CSS:**

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

}
ul, ol, dl {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
nav {
background-color: #bac9a9;
height: 35px;
}
ul#menu {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #bac9a9;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
width: 460px;
margin: auto;
}
ul#menu:after {
content: "";
background-image: url("../images/navbar-shadow-green.jpg");
height: 8px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-top: 30px;
}
ul#menu li {
float: left;
}
ul#menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #f3ffcf;
font-size: 22px;
padding: 5px 25px;
margin: 0px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #b2c1a2;
}
a.selected-page, ul#menu a.selected-page:hover {
background-color: #a6b396;
}
li#sub ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #bac9a9;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 4px;
overflow: hidden;
}
li#sub ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
border-top-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #a6b396;
text-align: left;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
ul#menu li#sub:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected-page">about</a></li>
    <li id="sub"><a href="#">work</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">photography</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[See this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t5QNq/1/)**

You just need to add hover bg color to the dropdown list.

```
ul#menu li#sub ul li:hover {
    background-color: #b2c1a2;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't cause the `a` to fill the `li`.. hover over the part on the right.. it is unclickable.

Comment: Oh yes right, didnt thought about it, thanks for the comment. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a `block` element, forcing it to fill the parent.:

```
ul#menu > li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nY9Bv/) - it works.